# Intent flag to start activity from foreground service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, foreground-service

I found many question about same problem at SO: Is there any way or intent flag combination to always starts activity from a foreground service? Almost all of these question doesn't have answer or completely outdated.
New restriction from Google in Android 10 (aug. 2020) described here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts.
My app has accessibility permission so this restriction should not be an issue.

Here the code example (Kotlin), that I use in foreground service to start activity of another app:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("scheme://command?params=present")
val tmpIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
tmpIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
tmpIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
tmpIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

Some additional explanation:
Initially, the device has opened MainActivity of a third-party application **A**, my application **B** has an active foreground service. After a certain delay, I use the above code to open completely clear new TargetActivity of application **A** using the url scheme, direct access to TargetActivity is prohibited in the third-party application (exported=false in manifest).

This code works in 70% of activity starts on the same device (tried multiple vendors and models), in other cases my application will open instead of a new target activity or nothing open (I couldn't find a certain addiction).
Can you please provide some intent flag combination or other advice to successfully starts activity in 100% of case?

*Important note: I am not trying to develop malware or anything bad, I just want to give users the ability to automate the process of interacting with a third-party application)*

Comment: I launch a dialogue themed activity from a service in one of my apps. From Android 10, I added: "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />". Also, the user has to have: settings -> app -> advanced -> special app access -> display over other apps -> app -> Allow display over other apps -> ON

Comment: Thank you for your help, access to SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission present in exclusions in Android 10 restrictions, but Android Go, for example, doesn't have this permission at all (according to [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)).
Also I already have accessibility permission that present in this list, I don't think that is the problem

Comment: Hi! I came up here from struggling on a my use case, a bit different than this one.
I need to collect Flow data from my Room's repo, within a Service, running in foreground. Here is my question on what I'm trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72621674/workmanager-in-android-to-handle-producer-consumer-pattern-for-data-received-in
Sometimes "collect" I used within a CoroutineScope (seems when I lock device's screen) stops listen for a while, until user's input...but I guess it could be something concerning startActivity with ACTION_VIEW and customscheme://
Thanks in advance!